# Flink throws NullPointerException when adding salt for the key and window aggregation on some field

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a program doing 2 phase aggregation to solve the data skew in my job. And I used a simple `ThreadLocalRandom` to generate a suffix to my original like :

```java
  private class KeyByTileWithSalt implements KeySelector<Type, String> {
    @Override
    public Long getKey(Type value) {
      return value.toString() + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 8);
    }
  }
```

But Flink throws NullPointerException when adding salt for the key I'm doing window aggregation on some field.

I found a [similar post](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg40924.html) on the flink-mail-list, and got the reason of the exception may occur, but I still cannot find the bug in my program about the `unstable of hash value`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink relies on the result of `keyBy` being deterministic across the cluster. This is necessary so that every node in the cluster has a consistent view regarding which node is responsible for processing each key. By having the key depend on `ThreadLocalRandom` you have violated this assumption.

What you can do instead is to add a field to each record that you populate with a random value during ingestion, and then use that field as the key.